# Adding subview to UITabBar that goes behind other UITabBar subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, subview

I am trying to add subview to UITabBar which should be behind other UITabBar Subviews.

I added the subview like this in my subclass of UITabBarController:

```
self.tabBar.addSubview(CustomTabBarController.xView!)
```

and then I send it to back as below:

```
self.tabBar.sendSubview(toBack: CustomTabBarController.xView!)
```

Problem is it doesn't go back and always appear infront. Also, even when this is the case, I am able to tap on tabbaritems. Is something wrong with UITabBar properties? or else, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A view that a subview of `view A` can't be behind `view A`. Think of a subview as being on the page of it's parent view.

It's also likely that a tab bar does not allow you to add subviews to it. Apple's UI controls are usually built to fully manage their view hierarchies, and the results of trying to insert subviews or otherwise mess with the view hierarchy are often undefined.

If you want a view to be behind another view the two views need to have the same parent view. You need to tell the tab bar's superview to add your new view behind the tab bar:

```
self.tabBar.superview. insertSubview(CustomTabBarController.xView!, 
  belowSubview: self.tabBar)
```

Also note that your use of force-unwrapping is ill-advised